# Relation Between Cross Product and Infinitesimal Rotations, Generators, Etc

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-theory, rotation, lie-algebra

Looking into the infinitesimal view of rotations from Lie, I noticed that the vector cross product can be written in terms of the generators of the rotation group $SO(3)$. For example:

$$\vec{\mathbf{A}} \times \vec{\mathbf{B}} =  (A^T \cdot J_x \cdot B)    \>\> \hat{i} + (A^T \cdot J_y \cdot B)    \>\> \hat{j} + (A^T \cdot J_z \cdot B)    \>\> \hat{k}$$

where,

$$J_x =  \begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix} \>\>\>;\>\>\>;J_y = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0\end{pmatrix} \>\>\>;\>\>\>;J_z = \begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix} $$

I couldn't help but think I was missing some profound connection here.  Why is the vector cross product seemingly intimately related to the generators of the $SO(3)$ rotation group?

Comment: The question currently has 3 migration votes. The question seems to be enough physics-inspired not to migrate to [math.se], so I'm temporarily closing it as a duplicate to avoid migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mystery dissipates when we consider how this generalizes to $D$-dimensional space. The cross product only makes sense when $D=3$, but the idea of using the antisymmetric part of $A_a B_b$ to represent an oriented element of area works for any $D$, as does the concept of a rotation in a given plane. So let's see what this looks like for aribtrary $D$.

We can express the vectors $A$ and $B$ in a canonical orthonormal basis, say
$$
\mathbf{E_1} =\left[\matrix{1\cr 0\cr 0\cr \vdots}\right]
\hskip1cm
\mathbf{E_2} =\left[\matrix{0\cr 1\cr 0\cr \vdots}\right]
\hskip1cm
\mathbf{E_3} =\left[\matrix{0\cr 0\cr 1\cr \vdots}\right]
\hskip1cm
\cdots
$$
and so on (again, this is for arbitrary $D$). I'm using boldface for a vector (represented here as a single-column matrix) and using non-boldface for its components. In this basis, we have
$$
\mathbf{A} = \sum_a A_a \mathbf{E}_a
\hskip2cm
\mathbf{B} = \sum_b B_b \mathbf{E}_b,
\tag{1}
$$
which gives
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^T-
\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}^T
&= ( \sum_a A_a \mathbf{E}_a)(\sum_b B_b \mathbf{E}_b^T)
- (\sum_b B_b \mathbf{E}_b)( \sum_a A_a \mathbf{E}_a^T)\\
&= \sum_{a,b} A_a B_b 
(\mathbf{E}_a\mathbf{E}_b^T -
\mathbf{E}_b\mathbf{E}_a^T) \\
&= \sum_{a,b} \frac{A_a B_b - B_a A_b}{2}
(\mathbf{E}_a\mathbf{E}_b^T -
\mathbf{E}_b\mathbf{E}_a^T)
\tag{2}
\end{align*}
where $T$ means transpose. The last step uses the fact that the quantity in parentheses changes sign if the indices $a$ and $b$ are exchanged, so the value of the sum is unchanged if we replace $A_a B_b$ with $-B_a A_b$. Therefore, the value of the sum is also unchanged if we replace $A_a B_b$ with half of $A_a B_b$ plus half of $-B_a A_b$. (In other words, the sum in the second-to-last line equals half of itself plus half of itself, which gives the last line.)

Now recognize that the matrix $\mathbf{E}_a\mathbf{E}_b^T - \mathbf{E}_b\mathbf{E}_a^T$ is the generator of rotations in the $a$-$b$ plane, and recognize that $A_a B_b - B_a A_b$ are the components of the "cross product" when $D=3$. Equation (2) shows how the phenomenon noted in the OP generalizes to arbitrary $D$.

The quantity $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^T-\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}^T$ is a matrix representation of a **bivector**, the oriented element of area defined by the two vectors $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$. The antisymmetry isolates their "mutually orthogonal part," which is the part we need for specifying an element of area. In fact, the bivector $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^T-\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}^T$ is the (unnormalized) generator of a rotation in the $\mathbf{A}$-$\mathbf{B}$ plane. The corresponding rotation matrix is
$$
R(\theta)=\exp\left(\theta\frac{\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^T-\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}^T}{N}\right)
\tag{3}
$$
where $N$ is defined by the condition 
$$
\left(\frac{\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^T-\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}^T}{N}\right)^3
=-\frac{\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^T-\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}^T}{N}.
\tag{4}
$$
Notice that the generator $\mathbf{E}_a\mathbf{E}_b^T - \mathbf{E}_b\mathbf{E}_a^T$ satisfies this condition with $N=1$. The minus sign is a consequence of antisymmetry, and this is also what ensures that $R$ is an orthogonal matrix: $R^TR =R R^T=I$.

When $D=3$, given any plane through the origin, there is a unique line through the origin that is orthogonal to the given plane. For this reason, we can get away with pretending that a bivector is a vector when $D=3$, and this is why we can define the "cross product" when $D=3$. (Vectors and bivectors still behave differently under reflections, though.) But for general $D$, such as $D=2$ or $D\geq 4$, that trick doesn't work, and we need to use a two-index quantity to represent a bivector.

Comment: Isn't `\vec{ }` easier than the boldface command?

Comment: @FGSUZ  You're right, "\vec{ }$ is a bit easier to type, although I was using a lot of copy-and-paste anyway. For readability, I usually default to boldface when lots of vectors are involved because it reduces the number of strokes that the eye has to parse; but one could argue that distinguishing between boldface and non-boldface causes some eyestrain, too. IMO, choosing good notation (consistent, concise, uncluttered, unambiguous, and a host of other mutually-conflicting requirements) is one of the hardest parts of physics!

Comment: @FGSUZ I'm glad you posted that comment, by the way, because it made me notice that I had accidentally made the subscripts boldface, too. That's fixed now.

Comment: I'm so glad you liked it, I was afraid you could be upset. I totally agree with the notation problem you state. As for me, I personally prefer vectors. I must admit that these bolds are particularly clear, but some books are terrible. Seeing an extra stroke is not neccesarily bad. It doesn't matter if there are too many, provided that they are clear. I prefer $dx/dt$ than $\dot{x}$, and it has more ink, but it is much clearerand less dangerous. I'm also sure that brains process it better haha, but that's just my view.

Comment: Dan, thanks for the response. Does the first line in one have a typo, missing a term? Also, I’m not following how you get from the the first line to the second, specifically with the coefficient. Lower where you talk about “defining” N is another spot you lost me. Any clarification would be much appreciated

Comment: @EthanT  I checked the multi-line equation and didn't see a typo, but it's possible that I'm just not being perceptive enough. I added an extra step and some extra explanation in the text following the equation. I also numbered more of the equations to make it easier to refer to them in comments, in case that's needed.

Comment: @EthanT  Regarding the definition of $N$, another way to say it is that if $A$ and $B$ happen to be orthogonal unit vectors like $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$, then $AB^T-BA^T$ is just one of the generators $J$, which satisfies $J^3=-J$ (with $N=1$). The way I wrote it in the answer works even if $A$ and $B$ aren't orthogonal to each other and even if they aren't unit vectors. If we define $J=AB^T-BA^T$ without the factor of $N$, then we'd still get $J^3\propto -J$ (this is not obvious at all, by the way; but it can be checked). The factor of $N$ is just used to absorb the proportionality factor.

Comment: @EthanT  The significance of the identity $J^3=-J$ is similar to the significance of the identity $i^3=-i$ for the imaginary unit $i$. This ensures that $\exp(i\theta)$ is a periodic function of $\theta$ with period $2\pi$, and $J^3=-J$ ensures that $\exp(\theta J)$ is a periodic function of $\theta$ with period $2\pi$, like a rotation matrix. To prove this, expand the exponential using $\exp(M)=\sum_{n\geq 0} M^n/n!$, which is valid for any matrix $M$. Then use $J^3=-J$ to write this as a linear combo of $1$, $J$, and $J^2$, with $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ in the coefficients.

Comment: Dan, I think my browser on my phone was acting up, because I don't see that typo now!  Also, I appreciate the extra clarification.  Pretty sure I can put it all together at this point.  Thanks again!